# How to query for the "parent" of an arbitrary child relationship in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to write the simplest, most efficient SQL query to retrieve a single `team` from a given `event`. But the `event` might not be directly related to the `team`, it might be related at any level in the table relationship hierarchy.

---

## Setup

Here's a simplistic representation of what my schema looks like:

[image]

A couple things to note:

- `teams` can have many `collections`, `apps`, and `webhooks`.
- `collections` can also have many `webhooks`.
- `webhooks` can belong to either a `team` or `collection`, but only one.
- `events` can belong to any object, but only one.

This seems like a fairly basic setup that most SaaS-type companies would have (eg. Slack or Stripe). Everything is grouped under a "team" which users can then interact with as members.

---

## Problem

Given that setup, I'd like to create a SQL query that solves...

> Find the team of an event by `id`.

I can easily write queries that find the parent team either directly, or indirectly via a specific means. For example...

> Find the team of a **directly** related "team event".

```
SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN events ON events.team_id = teams.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}
```

Or...

> Find the team of an **indirectly** related "collection event".

```
SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN collections ON collections.team_id = teams.id
JOIN events ON events.collection_id = collections.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}
```

Webhooks get a more complex, because they can be related in two different ways...

> Find the team of an **indirectly** related "webhook event".

```
SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN collections ON collections.team_id = teams.id
JOIN webhooks AS team_webhooks ON team_webhooks.team_id = teams.id
JOIN webhooks AS collection_webhooks ON collection_webhooks.collection_id = collections.id
JOIN events AS team_webhook_events ON team_webhook_events.webhook_id = team_webhooks.id
JOIN events AS collection_webhook_events ON collection_webhook_events.webhook_id = collection_webhooks.id
WHERE team_webhook_events.id = ${id}
OR collection_webhook_events.id = ${id}
```

I'm not sure if I should be writing it like that, or by using `UNION` instead...

```
SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN webhooks ON webhooks.team_id = teams.id
JOIN events ON events.webhook_id = webhooks.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}

UNION

SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN collections ON collections.team_id = teams.id
JOIN webhooks ON webhooks.collection_id = collections.id
JOIN events ON events.webhook_id = webhooks.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}
```

...unsure which is better for performance.

---

As you can see, there are a lot of different ways for a single event to be related to a given team, via all those paths! So when I try to write the "all encompassing" query, it ends up being super complex...

## Potential Solution #1

Doing it the `UNION` way, I think I can just make a bunch of queries, and union them all together, although this seems like it might be wasteful?

```
SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN events ON events.team_id = teams.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}

UNION

SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN apps ON apps.team_id = teams.id
JOIN events ON events.app_id = apps.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}

UNION

SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN collections ON collections.team_id = teams.id
JOIN events ON events.collection_id = collections.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}

UNION

SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN webhooks ON webhooks.team_id = teams.id
JOIN events ON events.webhook_id = webhooks.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}

UNION

SELECT teams.*
FROM teams
JOIN collections ON collections.team_id = teams.id
JOIN webhooks ON webhooks.collection_id = collections.id
JOIN events ON events.webhook_id = webhooks.id
WHERE events.id = ${id}
```

## Potential Solution #2

Using multiple `JOIN`s I think I might be able to join all of the different combinations of event owners together, with their relationship to `teams`? Although this also seems like a lot of `JOIN`s...

```
SELECT teams.*
FROM teams

JOIN apps ON apps.team_id = teams.id
JOIN collections ON collections.team_id = teams.id
JOIN webhooks AS team_webhooks ON team_webhooks.team_id = teams.id
JOIN webhooks AS collection_webhooks ON collection_webhooks.collection_id = collections.id

JOIN events AS app_events ON app_events.app_id = apps.id
JOIN events AS collection_events ON collection_events.collection_id = collections.id
JOIN events AS team_events ON team_events.team_id = teams.id
JOIN events AS collection_webhook_events ON collection_webhook_events.webhook_id = collection_webhooks.id
JOIN events AS team_webhook_events ON team_webhook_events.webhook_id = team_webhooks.id

WHERE app_events.id = ${id}
OR collection_events.id = ${id}
OR team_events.id = ${id}
OR collection_webhook_events.id = ${id}
OR team_webhook_events.id = ${id}
```

---

## Questions

- Are either of those potential solutions the best way to do it?
- Is there a more efficient way to write it?
- Is there a simpler, easier-to-read-later way to write it?

---

**Edit:** I don't think this question is a duplicate!

Yesterday, I asked ["How to query for nested relationships in SQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267473/how-to-simply-and-efficiently-query-for-nested-relationships-in-sql), which involves a similar data structure (because it's the same one), and was written in a similar way. But, as far as I can tell, that question is actually the *inverse* of this one.

In the first, I was asking how to...

> **Find all of the events that are related (directly or indirectly) to a given user by ID.** Or put more generically, given a "parent"'s ID, find all of its possible descendants in the tree-like data model.

But in this one, I'm asking how to...

> **Find the team of an arbitrary event by ID.** Or put more generically, given an arbitrary "child"'s ID, which can be attached to the tree-like data model at any level of the hierarchy, find its matching parent. (It's essentially the inverse of the first question.)

And as far as I can tell, they involve different solutions. The first seems to involve performing a series of queries as you traverse through the tree, collecting all of the events. The second (this one), I'm less sure about, but seems to require building up all of the joined models first, and then checking to see if which of them match the specific event.

Please help me to mark it as not a duplicate!

**Double edit:** Okay, no longer marked as duplicate! Thanks :D

Comment: This question doesn't seem so different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267473/how-to-simply-and-efficiently-query-for-nested-relationships-in-sql.

Comment: `UNION` is the way to go here.

Comment: Or, you could redesign your schema to always include a `team_id` value to your tables (then you could use multi-column foreign keys with `MATCH SIMPLE`, which is the default anyway). This way, you'll never have to write advanced queries to find out which of objects are related to a specific team.

Comment: The schema could be something like this: http://rextester.com/OCSHJH10914

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff thank you for taking the time to look at both of my questions! I've edited this one to explain why I don't think it's actually a duplicate. My fault for asking in a similar way and using the same structure/diagram, since I was asking them at similar times. But I think this question is actually the inverse, and complementary to the first one. Please take a look and help me un-mark it as a duplicate! Thank you so much :D

Comment: You start by asking for a *query to retrieve a **single** team from a given event* - only to go on talking about lists of teams. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: You ask for a *single* team in your first sentence, but your solutions return sets of teams.

Answer (score 3):

**Find the team of an arbitrary event by ID**:

Take left joins from events table and see which object returns a team_id use that.

```
select coalesce(e.team_id,a.team_id,c.team_id,w.team_id) eteam_id 
from events e 
   left join apps a on e.app_id=a.id 
   left join collections c on c.id=e.collection_id 
   left join webhooks w on w.id=e.webhook_id 
   left join teams t on t.id=e.team_id 
where e.id=${id};
```

Just for completeness if you want all data for resultant team:

```
select t.* from teams t 
join 
(select coalesce(e.team_id,a.team_id,c.team_id,w.team_id) eteam_id
from events e left join apps a on e.app_id=a.id 
left join collections c on c.id=e.collection_id 
left join webhooks w on w.id=e.webhook_id 
left join teams t on t.id=e.team_id 
where e.id=1) t1 
on t.id=eteam_id;
```

Comment: Using `select coalesce(e.team_id, a.team_id, c.team_id, w.team_id)` will return a single field instead of one populated field among a bunch of `null`

Answer (score 2):

Just `OR` the conditions together.

Since you are only interested in `teams`, you dont need to *join* the other tables (that *could* generate duplicates), only for the *existence* of records with certain (matching) values in the other tables.

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM events e
        WHERE e.SOME_FIELD = SOME_EVENT
        AND
          (     team_id = t.id  -- direct reference
        OR EXISTS (             -- reference via webhooks
                SELECT 1 FROM webhooks w
                WHERE  w.id = e.webhook_id
                AND w.team_id = t.id
                )
        OR EXISTS (             -- reference via apps
                SELECT 1 FROM apps a
                WHERE  a.id = e.app_id
                AND a.team_id = t.id
                )
        OR EXISTS (             -- reference via collections
                SELECT 1 FROM collections c
                WHERE  c.id = e.collection_id
                AND c.team_id = t.id
                )
        OR EXISTS (             -- reference via webhooks*collections
                SELECT 1 FROM webhooks w
                JOIN collections c ON w.collection_id = c.id
                WHERE  w.id = e.webhook_id
                AND c.team_id = t.id
                WHERE c.team_id = t.id
                )
          )
        ) ;
```